# Find general solution using variation of parameters for $y'' - 4y' + 4y = e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

By inspection, I notice that $y_1 = e^{x}$ is one solution. To find $y_2$, I use the quadratic equation, solve and get $x = \pm 0$ so $y_2 = c_1e^{0x} + c_2e^{0x} = c_1 + c_2$.

Once I have $y_1, y_2$ I think I need to solve the system of equations
$$\begin{align}
v'_1 y_1 + v'_2 y_2 &= 0 \\
v'_1 y'_1 + v'_2 y'_2 &= e^x \\
\end{align}$$

Here is where I get stuck though and I am not able to solve the system of equations for $v'_1$ and $v'_2$ which makes me think somehow my general solutions are wrong, but I am not sure.

Comment: Hint: Cramer's Rule.

Comment: I don't get why I need to use Cramer's rule

Comment: Are you sure about those roots of the characteristic equation? Even if they were both $0$, that’s not what the homogeneous solution looks like. Do you remember what to do when there’s a repeated root?

Comment: I did the quadratic equation incorrectly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'' - 4y' + 4y = e^x$$
multiply both sodes by $e^{-2x}$
Is equivalent to:
$$(ye^{-2x})''=e^{-x}$$
Integrate twice.
$$(ye^{-2x})'=-e^{-x}+c_1$$
$$ye^{-2x}=e^{-x}+c_1x+c_2$$
$$ \implies y=e^{x}+e^{2x}(c_1x+c_2)$$

Answer (score 2):

The equation $y'' - 4y' + 4y = 0$ has solutions of the form $c_1e^{2x}+c_2xe^{2x}$. Combining this with the fact that $y'' - 4y' + 4y = e^x$ has $e^x$ as a particular solution, the general solution is $y=e^x+c_1e^{2x}+c_2xe^{2x}$.